# why the printThis.js is printing two pages when only one has information?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do use the printThis.js to print info from a MVC Razor View, for the info I need to get printed, one page is more than enough but when I send from the web to the printer it always gives to the user two pages, one with the due info in the correct format according to the div and the second one in blank(not any info to print)

this is the code in my view

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#printer').click(function () {
            $('#contenido').printThis();
        });
```

this is my button

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="printer">
            Imprimir
        </button>
```

and this is the div

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="contenido">
            <h4><b>INFO...</b></h4>
            <ul>
                ... info to print
            </ul>
        </div>
```

could you please tell me how to achieve to print just one page?

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure the page is at 99% for print in CSS

```
@media print {
    html, body {
        height: 99%;    
    }
}
```